# Spring Boot LDAP Auth

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

In spring boot LDAP security, is there a way for authenticated users to access the web without encrypting their password? I have LDAP repository and I don't have access to the password attribute. I can only login to LDAP and check whether I'm authenticated.